# GUI enables on reboot Ubuntu 18 post disabling

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I tried disabling UI on Ubuntu 18.04.5 fresh install on Virtualbox with below command.

Ran below command
sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

Removed the word splash below line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

then run the below commands sequentially,

```
sudo update-grub
sudo systemctl stop gdm3.service gdm.service
sudo systemctl disable gdm3.service gdm.service
```

But after restarting again the GUI comes up. Any Idea what I might be missing?

> **NOTE**: I also tried setting runlevels multi-user.target etc. But none are working

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related and should have been posted on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you setting up the wished target as default?

Run this command:
`sudo systemctl get-default`

For point it at CLI interface, you should get a `multi-user.target`

If not, set it up as default and reboot: `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target`

Comment: I am getting `graphical.target` in output

Comment: Now working as you suggested.